# Actionbar implementation in 2.3 without using third party jars

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have to utilize the `ActionBar` in my application, but I am working on Android 2.3. Would it be possible to accomplish without using third party jars like **"actionbarsherlock.com"**, ie is there any support available from Android itself?

I tried the link below from previous posts, but as the Android Developers Site has been modified I'm not able to find anything [there](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You answered your own question really - Actionbarsherlock (and others) exist to provide backward compatibility for older android versions (2.x and below), as the native actionbar is not available for all Android versions. If it was, no one would probably have built the third party libraries that implement the basic functionality (although they might extend it).

If you do not want to use a third party library then you will have to implement your own OR only support Android 3.0 onwards, which is probably not the best of ideas.

In my *opinion* implementing your own will be slow and unnecessary as ABS is a great implementation and allows the native actionbar to do its job on the versions of Android that support it thus providing the same user experience to all Android users (well - 2.2 and up). Jake Warton tries to make sure that ABS only implements the native functionality - nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: thnx for ur response.I do understand ABS is great library,but wanted to know any android support library exists like android-support-v4.jar...also in developer site they have mentioned link for backward compatibility but nothing is there.

Comment: Not a problem, and yes most links to the dev site seem to be broken, which is incredibly irritating. If you need help with ABS I produced a video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY